# How can I use multiple b-form-radio-group avoiding visual interference among them?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I'm new using Vue and specifically Bootstrap Vue and I'm trying to build a form with multiple radio groups.

My problem is that when I change the value in one of them the others don't change their values (this was checked with Vue DevTools) but visually it looks like none of the values are selected

I don't know what is wrong with my approach

I post here a simplified version of the code looking for some help, thanks in advance:

```
<template>
  <div>

    <b-form-group label="Radio group 1" v-slot="{ ariaDescribedby }">
      <b-form-radio-group
        id="radio-group-1"
        v-model="selected1"
        :options="options1"
        :aria-describedby="ariaDescribedby"
        name="radio-options"
      ></b-form-radio-group>

    </b-form-group>
      <b-form-group label="Radio Group 2" v-slot="{ ariaDescribedby }">
        <b-form-radio-group
          id="radio-group-2"
          v-model="selected2"
          :options="options2"
          :aria-describedby="ariaDescribedby"
          name="radio-options"
        ></b-form-radio-group>
      </b-form-group>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        selected1: 'first',
        options1: [
          { text: 'First', value: 'first' },
          { text: 'Second', value: 'second' },
        ],
        selected2: 'one',
        options2: [
          { text: 'One', value: 'one' },
          { text: 'Two', value: 'two' },
       ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You don't see the blue selected dot when choosing any of them?

Comment: Yes, when I choose a value in the first one the blue selected dot is visible, but if i choose one of the second radio group, the blue dot in the first one disappears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since both `<b-form-radio-group>` elements have the same name, "radio-options", visually they are treated like one group.  The different `v-model` would still function correctly but this isn't what you want visually.  Give the second group a different name:

```html
<b-form-radio-group
  id="radio-group-2"
  v-model="selected2"
  :options="options2"
  :aria-describedby="ariaDescribedby"
  name="radio-options2"   
></b-form-radio-group>
```

Here I changed it to `radio-options2`.